# Update field where one date field is less than other date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I want set some records in my database. There is some records where field last_login is less than create_at. So, I wanna set the field last_login_at this records with NULL.

But, the query below its not working.

```
update database.users 
set last_login_at = NULL
where last_login_at < created_at;
```

I do some tests, the query below works:

```
SELECT * FROM database.users
WHERE last_login_at < created_at;
```

And this query works too:

```
UPDATE database.users 
SET last_login_at = NULL 
WHERE id = 10;
```

Why the first query doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show your DB schema? and what is the error ?

Comment: first query '...last_login_at < create_at...' and second '...last_login_at < created_at...'

Comment: Oh .-. 09:28:50 Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect. 0.000 sec

Comment: Well, I know now what I wanna do, thanks =]

Comment: your query seems fine, please check your naming format like spelling

Answer (score 1):

`created_at` is not equal to `create_at`. Error is due to a typo.

Change to this:

```
update database.users 
set last_login_at = NULL
where last_login_at < created_at;
```

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake when I typed here.